# Session Cookie without HttpOnly flag set

Tags: php, javascript, apache, security

I have joust built a website with a login system. After I've just got ready I have scanned it with Acunetix, but I got the following message:

Session Cookie without HttpOnly flag set
Session Cookie without Secure flag set (i guess this is only if I have SSL connection)

So my question would be, that how can I set HttpOnly flag for all my Session data? I'm just using sessions when I log in the users. I'm giving them a session with their userID number and than I'm getting data using that userID.

Is there any simple way that I can set ALL of the session HTTPOnly and secure them, so noone can touch them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either change settings in php.ini, or via `ini_set()` calls to change `session.cookie_secure` and `session.cookie_httponly` values to `true`.

Alternately, you can use `session_set_cookie_params()` before starting your session to get the effect you are looking for.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: If I set it in the PHP.ini, it will be secure and this problem will be solved by that?

Comment: Yes, you should pass the security scan once you have both ini values set properly (either in php.ini or at run time via the other methods mentioned).

Comment: I have looked at my php.ini at webmin but didn't finf anything like session.cookie_httponly :( I have version 5.2, is it okay?

Comment: It could be that your install of php does not have this explicitly set in ini (or you are looking at wrong ini file - like that in CLI directory in some installs).  This value is available as of PHP 5.2.0, so even if not in your ini file, you can add a line for it, or just change at run time.

Comment: Thank you. But can I use session.cookie_secure with a non-SSL domain?

Comment: Yes secure cookies will only be transmitted from the browser client to the server when using HTTPS.

Comment: "session.cookie_secure specifies whether cookies should only be sent over secure connections" so they will be sent only is you are using HTTPS(reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [this excellent site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Using_PHP_to_set_HttpOnly) for this question. It comes down to setting it in the sessions-section of your php.ini (or via the appropriate runtime function):

```
session.cookie_httponly = True
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also just set the `httponly` flag to `false` when you use PHP's [`setcookie`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

```
// params: name, value, expiration, path, domain, secure, http-only
setcookie('session-cookie-key', 'data', 0, '/', 'example.com', true, false);
```