# Is session.cookie_secure in php.ini automatic?

Tags: php, session, cookies, httponly

Simple answer requested:
If I put

```
session.cookie_httponly=On
session.cookie_secure=On
```

in the php.ini file for my website, will that automatically turn all the php cookies to secure and httponly, or will I still need to put in true, true into parameter slots 6 and 7 in the cookie itself?

Comment: Tried testing it? Based on the naming, I think this only affects the session cookies used by php itself and not any "custom" set cookies.

Comment: Was the question not clear. I don't understand your answer at all.

Comment: @MrTux I'm not referring to 'custom' set cookies, just the standard php cookie, i.e.
    setcookie('name','value',time,'/','mysite.com',true,true)

Comment: @MrTux,
Well, you've downvoted the question so no one else will bother with it, but you haven't answered it.

Comment: I suppose it got downvoted because the question can be easily solved by using google and also the question isn't really clear: What are ```parameter slots 6 and 7```?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session Cookie without HttpOnly flag set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075003/session-cookie-without-httponly-flag-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes. Setting this in php.ini is enough (however, I only saw "True" as the setting used instead of "On").

- [Session Cookie without HttpOnly flag set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075003/session-cookie-without-httponly-flag-set)
- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#Using_PHP_to_set_HttpOnly

You can verify this by setting these values, restarting your webserver and accessing your site with a browser, e.g. Firefox. Then open "site information", and choose "security" tab and click on cookies. There you can see if it's marked as secure.

Comment: Thank you. I did Google it many times as well as look in Stack, but the questions were all a little different and even php.net did not specifically state what I wanted, which was, a clear answer. You've also provided references so again, thank you. I'll follow them up to find a fuller explanation. 

Lastly, thank you for taking the extra time after your initial comment.